# Make Guns Available?

Tags: xcom-2

So there is a button to make Armor and Utility Items available, that is take away from those not on the mission, but there does not seem to be an easy way to make guns available.  With modded weapons, this is a big pain to switch the guns out from injured people.  Am I missing a better way to do this?

Comment: Have you noticed that you can do this from the staging screen where you get your soldiers ready to go? When you go to edit somebody, the arrows at the bottom will let you switch to the person with the gun you want and remove it, even if they aren't on the mission.

Comment: Yes, but the pain there is the arrows don't seem to be in any sequence?  Unless it is rank.  At that point it is easier to find the person in a list rather than one by one, imo

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure what sequence they're in. I assume it's rank. It seems like it's the same , or at least similar (rank ordering can change), each time.

Comment: I've noticed that sometimes, the weapons that I want are just available for selection from the loadout menu... but sometimes not. It presumably depends on the exact status of the soldier that previously had them, but I haven't figured out exactly what's going on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no way to do this in the base-game, you'll have to go through and remove them one-by-one.

However, fortunately there is a mod that adds a button to remove them all at once:  [Strip Primary Weapons](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=618504171)